# Syntax error in query expression

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

```
string q = "UPDATE tableAbsensi SET Absen_keluar =('"+(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm"))+"') WHERE ID ='"+ idkaryawantxt.Text.ToString() + "' AND Tanggal ='" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

I think I have error in my syntax, can you guys help me? Thanks

here's the picture of error :
http://sadpanda.us/images/1889033-X8SIZZN.jpg

Comment: Looking at the code you provided you are not closing the single quote at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a quote. This:

```
AND Tanggal ='" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

should probably be

```
AND Tanggal ='" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "');
```

But you really should use parameters instead to prevent errors like these and also [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

### Please don't do that!

You should never use string concatenations in your sql queries. Always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

With this concatenations, you might forget to use some comma, quotes, brackets etc..

Also use the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `Connection` and `Command`. For example;

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = com.CreateCommand())
{
   string s = "UPDATE tableAbsensi SET Absen_keluar=? WHERE ID=? AND Tanggal=?";
   cmd.CommandText = s;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@absen", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm"));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idkaryawantxt.Text.ToString());   
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal",  DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")); 
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code.  Always use parameters and issues like this caused by formatting just go away.  To learn why and how to use parameters, [check this out](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).